# Добавление поддержки Windows Hello

Tags: c#, ассемблер, windows-10, драйвер

Попросили добавить в сканер отпечатка пальца ZK4500 Fingerprint Reader поддержку Windows Hello, и не понимаю, как это сделать. Подскажите пожалуйста как.

Пробовал такой метод: качаю драйвера для этого устройства, нахожу подобное устройство, но с поддержкой Windows Hello, и тоже качаю для него драйвер. Декомпилирую в C# оба файла, нахожу во втором упоминания Windows Hello, не хитрыми методами добавляю в первый файл, обратно компилирую. Пробовал с Cobo C2 в качестве второго драйвера на Windows 10 1809 x64, используя виртуальную машину с той же системой. сразу встаёт вопрос: а как декомпилить asm в c#? если вы это знаете, также скажите как это сделать, буду очень рад :)

Comment: `как декомпилить asm в c#` никгода о такой туле не слышал

Comment: tym32167 хорошо, учту.